# jQuery DOM traversal sub menu descendants

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, dom-traversal

I have created a repsonsive two level navigation using jQuery and it works quite well apart from one thing - the 2nd level (submenu) links are causing the next sub menu to open when they should not be opening anything at all.

```
        <nav>
            <h2><a href="#">NAV</a></h2>
            <ul id="dropNav">
                <li><a href="#">This site</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">DD Link 01</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">DD Link 02</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">DD Link 03</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">About us</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">DD Link 01</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">DD Link 02</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">DD Link 01</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">DD Link 02</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">DD Link 03</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">DD Link 04</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">DD Link 05</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Prices</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">DD Link 01</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Social</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">DD Link 01</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">DD Link 02</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">DD Link 03</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">DD Link 04</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$(function() {
    var pull        = $('nav > h2');
        menu        = $('nav ul:first');
        menuHeight  = menu.height();

        $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            menu.slideToggle();
    });
});


$("#dropNav > li").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).siblings().children().next().slideUp(); // when opening a sub
    $(this).find("ul").slideToggle(); // toggle the submenu
});
```

});

See my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lonewolfweb/5g0bh73k/)

How can I deactivate these 2nd level links?

Comment: I don't use jQuery much (or at all, really) but could you try setting the thing (don't know its name) for `"#dropNav > li > ul > il"` to an empty function? If that works, lemme know and I'll put it in an answer.

Comment: how about `$("#dropNav > li").not("#dropNav > li > ul > li").on("click", function(e) {`

Comment: I don't really have an answer for you, but note two things: 1) If you change the hrefs of your top-level menu items (About Us, Portfolio, etc.) you'll notice that hovering over any submenu item actually shows the href for the next top-level menu item.  That's why the next submenu is opening - it actually thinks you're clicking on it, which is bizarre. 2) If you remove the CSS media query and its contained rules, this problem goes away (albeit the formatting gets messed up).  So it seems that one of those rules (probably the one with ":hover") is causing your problem.

Comment: Good spot! A second (or third) set of eyes always helps. I must have tried 100 different selector combos and it was the css. I have updated the JS Fiddle again and it now works quite well but I need to tweak a little more to stop the submenu links closing the submenu when they are clicked and to add some more jQuery to close the menu's when clicking elsewhere on the page. http://jsfiddle.net/Lonewolfweb/5g0bh73k/25/

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on phari's answer, it looks to be a CSS positioning problem.

```
/* set up sub nav hover */

nav ul li a {
padding:10px 25px 10px 25px;
display:block;
/*position:relative;*/ /*commenting out this line seemed to fix it*/
}
```

You could also take a look at the jQueryUI which has a handy accordion function.

[jQueryUI Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

Comment: Thanks. I have used the accordion before but I'm trying to make a my own custom version.